# How to pass parameter through "Run-->Parameters" in Inno Setup?

Tags: parameters, inno-setup

I worked with passing command line parameters through Command prompt. `(/d<name>=<value>)`. It's work.

Later I found `"parameters"` option in `"Run"` menu of "Inno Setup 5". I tried but failed to pass.
My Attempts

`"/dWish=Hello"`

`/dWish=Hello`

`"Wish=Hello"`

`Wish="Hello"`

`Wish="Hello"`

`Wish=Hello`

And access like `{#Wish}`. But compilation filed with error `undeclared identifier "Wish"`

**This is for option**
[image]

Comment: They are passed to the built setup, not to the compiler.

Comment: I'm sorry, I found Compile option on Build. There is no Build Setup.

Comment: I tried with this `iscc "/dName=Demo" "Installation_Script.iss"`.    It's working. Now i want pass `Name=Demo` through Inno Setup UI. Means Run==> Parameters section. With out using Command Prompt

Comment: You cannot. The Inno Setup IDE run (F9) first builds the script (if necessary) and then runs the built setup passing those parameters. Those IDE run parameters are not passed to the compiler. But you may try e.g. [`Inno Script Studio`](https://www.kymoto.org/products/inno-script-studio) which might have some IDE options to set parameters passed to the compiler.

Comment: Neither Inno Script Studio or InnoIDE support passing command line parameters to the compiler either, at least in the versions of those I have available.

Comment: Yes @TLama  @KenWhite. I too test with Inno Script Studio. Same issue. I'll manage by using Command prompt. But only only doubt is `What is the use of  "Run==>parameter"` will use?

Comment: That's for [`setup command line parameters`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline).

Answer (score 5):

Settings configured via `Run` -> `Parameters` are used to pass instructions to the installer being executed after compilation, not the build compiler (`ISCC`). Options that may be set are available in the InnoSetup help under [Setup Command Line Parameters](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline).

To pass parameters to the compiler itself, run the compiler from the command-line, and use the `/D` switch. So to set variable `VAR` to value `val`, use:

```
iscc "/dVAR=val" "MyInstallerScript.iss"
```

The `ISCC.exe` program is located in:

`%programfiles%\Inno Setup 5\ISCC.exe`